# (Telegram бот) Ошибка в CallbackQuery

Tags: java, telegram, бот

не могу понять почему Событие CallbackQuery не обновляется при нажатии на InlineKeyboardButton.

Главный класс:

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingCommandBot {
    //...//
    @Override
    public void processNonCommandUpdate(Update update) {
        sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), "" + update.hasCallbackQuery());
    }
```

Код inlineKeyboardMarkup

```
public class ButtonsInMessage{
    public static InlineKeyboardMarkup languageButtons(){
        InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> buttonsInRow = new ArrayList<>();

        InlineKeyboardButton english = new InlineKeyboardButton();
        english.setText("English ");
        english.setCallbackData("english");
        buttonsInRow.add(english);

        rowList.add(buttonsInRow);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. нашел ошибку, в `sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), "" + update.hasCallbackQuery());` надо использовать `update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId().toString()`